# Restful Spring MVC: The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (date format)

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

Model

```
private int id;
@NotEmpty 
private String fname;
@NotEmpty
private String lname;
@DateTimeFormat (pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy")
private Date birthday;
private String description;
```

Restful ws (POST Method)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public 
@ResponseBody 
Contact save_api(@RequestBody @Valid Contact contact) { 
System.out.println("asdasd");
conService.insert(contact);
return contact;
}
```

Test service (json data)
{"fname":"Co 1 nguoi Khung", "lname":"Haha", "birthday":"10/10/2010", "description":""}

I post data with MM/dd/yyyy format (as model), but something error here: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

However, if I post this data:
{"fname":"Co 1 nguoi Khung dung gan da", "lname":"Lan", "birthday":"2010-10-10", "description":""}
It is successful, save data into database.

Who can help me"?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Your test data (as provided) is in the form: "10-10-2010", but your format specifier suggests it should be "10/10/2010".

Comment: sorry, I have just corrected it, use this format "10/10/2010" and get the same error.